# SQL Server index and poor execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have an existing SQL Server database where I cannot modify the structure or the queries ran and am facing an issue with poor execution impacting performance and ultimately cloud database cost.

*Kindly note my experience with SQL is quite limited and after multiple googling and trial and errors, still did not achieve acceptable result. Any tips or help is much appreciated, thank you all in advance. If you would like me to provide more information, feel free to comment and I will update the post accordingly.*

## The issue

I have two tables: `Table1` and `Table2`. `Table2` references `Table1` via `TABLE1_ID` field and we run a SQL query extracting info from `Table2` while filtering on `Table1` ( `INNER JOIN` I believe).

Using the following query:

```sql
DECLARE @P1 datetime
DECLARE @P2 datetime

SELECT
    dbo.Table2.VALUE
FROM
    dbo.Table2,
    dbo.Table1
WHERE
    -- joins Table1/Table2
        dbo.Table1.ID = dbo.Table2.TABLE1_ID 

     -- filters on Table1
    AND dbo.Table1.TIMESTAMP between @P1 and @P2
```

My understanding would be that the database engine would first filter on `Table1` then do the join with `Table2`, however, the execution plan I am seeing is using a `Merge Join` implying `Table2` is fully scanned then joined with filtered results from `Table1`.

[image]

## What I have tried

I have tried the following, attempting to identify the problem or optimize performance:

1. **Optimization attempt** Creating an `FK` constraint
2. **Optimization attempt** Creating other indexes with/without include columns
3. **Issue identification** Changing the query to select value from both `Table1` and `Table2` and see the difference

## Re-creating the issue

The following script could allow you to re-create the database structure (please note it will insert 1M records into both tables):

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1] (
    [ID] [decimal](10, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [VALUE] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Table1_TIMESTAMP]  DEFAULT (sysdatetime()) FOR [TIMESTAMP]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Table1_ID] ON [dbo].[Table1]
(
    [ID] ASC
)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Table1_TIMESTAMP] ON [dbo].[Table1]
(
    [TIMESTAMP] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([ID])
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2] (
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TABLE1_ID] [decimal](10, 0) NOT NULL,
    [VALUE] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Table2_TABLE1_ID] ON [dbo].[Table2]
(
    [TABLE1_ID] ASC
) INCLUDE ([VALUE])
GO

Declare @Id decimal(10,0) = 1
DECLARE @Now datetime = SYSDATETIME()

While @Id <= 1000000
Begin 
   Insert Into dbo.Table1 values ('T1_' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10)), DATEADD (ss, @Id, @Now))
   Insert Into dbo.Table2 values (@Id, 'T2_' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10)))
   Print @Id
   Set @Id = @Id + 1
End
GO
```

Then you can try to run the following query:

```sql
DECLARE @P1 datetime
DECLARE @P2 datetime

SELECT
    dbo.Table2.VALUE
FROM
    dbo.Table2,
    dbo.Table1
WHERE
        dbo.Table1.ID = dbo.Table2.TABLE1_ID
    AND dbo.Table1.TIMESTAMP between @P1 and @P2
```

Answer (score 2):

> My understanding would be that the database engine would first filter on Table1 then do the join with Table2,

Wrong.  SQL is a *descriptive* language, not a procedural language.  A SQL query describes the result set, not the methods used for creating it.

The SQL parser and optimizer are responsible for generating the execution plan.  The only requirement is that the results from the execution plan match the results described by the query.

If you want to control the execution plan, then SQL Server offers hints, so you can require a nested loop join.  In general, such hints are used to *avoid* nested loop joins.

Actually, your query is reading the *index*.  This is a more efficient way of "filtering" the data than actually reading the data and filtering.  This looks like an optimal execution plan.

Further, don't use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip, indeed it works best when specify `INNER LOOP JOIN` since it does not have to read the entire index of `Table2` . Is there a way to write down the SQL query to be compliant with both Oracle and SQL Server? If not, I guess we will manage with our devs or create a store procedure.